# Can I use another cfswitch statement within the same cfswitch case

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Can I use another cfswitch statement within the same cfswitch case?

```
<CFSWITCH EXPRESSION="nameOfPg">
  <CFCASE VALUE="ClassMenu" >
    <!---do something--->
  </CFCASE>
  <CFCASE VALUE="ReportsMenu">
    <CFSWITCH EXPRESSION="#nameOfPg#">
      <CFCASE VALUE="StudentMenu">
        <!---do something--->
      </CFCASE>
      <CFCASE VALUE="DetailsMenu">
        <!---do something--->
      </CFCASE>
    </CFSWITCH>
  </CFCASE>
  <CFDEFAULTCASE>
    <!---do something--->
  </CFDEFAULTCASE>
</CFSWITCH>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why not simply just try? Worst case you'll get an error and it'll tell you you can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The `EXPRESSION` attribute can be dynamic (e.g. a variable such as `nameOfPg`), but pay attention to the hashes `#`.

`nameOfPg` (your top CFSWITCH) evaluates the string, not the actual value of the variable `nameOfPg`. To resolve a variable in an attribute, you need to use hashes `#` like you did in your inner CFSWITCH: `#nameOfPg#`.

Fix your code:

```
<CFSWITCH EXPRESSION="#nameOfPg#">
  <CFCASE VALUE="ClassMenu" >
    <!---do something--->
```

and you should be good.

On a side note: `CFCASE` on the other hand does not allow the use of dynamic values (due to to the way a switch works in Java/ColdFusion). You always have to use a static value here like you do right now. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: wow, I see now. I was missing the hashes. Thanks for the help. 
The example code I used same EXPRESSION (eg. #nameOfPg#), but I want to know, Can I use different EXPRESSION into both cfswitches?

Comment: Yes, they can be different.